# kivymd, creating a splash loading page as animation I couldn't code it instead I use Gif not working why?

Tags: python, kivy, gif, kivy-language, kivymd

Hello Guys i create a page using kivymd using an gif because i couldn't code it so i make a video for it than i convert it to gif.
the point is the code doesn't work and the error wasn't clear any help please

this the code of the splashloading.kv

```
MDFloatLayout:
    md_bg_color:1,1,1,1
    md_bg_color: (255/255, 250/255, 245/255, 1)
        Image:
            source:"assets/start.gif"
            size_hint:.50,.50
            pos_hint:{"center_x":.5,"center_y":.8}
```

and the code for the main.py I comment the first page just to see the splashloading page.

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.core.text import LabelBase

Window.size =(350, 580)


class StartPage(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        LabelBase.register(name='Lemonada',fn_regular='fonts/Lemonada-VariableFont_wght.ttf')
        global screen_manager
        screen_manager = ScreenManager()
        #screen_manager.add_widget(Builder.load_file("firstUse.kv"))
        #screen_manager.add_widget(Builder.load_file("main.kv"))
        screen_manager.add_widget(Builder.load_file("splashloading.kv"))
        return screen_manager
    def Login(self, *args):
        screen_manager.current = "Login"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    StartPage().run()
```

the error:
[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the gif, but I can give you code for a video player that has worked fairly smoothly in some of my projects.

Need to create a **Video player** class which can then be used in the .kv file

**In .kv file**

```
# This is only the code for the widget, the structure around it is not included
PlayerOpen:
    id: player_open
    opacity: 1
    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
    state: 'play'
```

**Python code defining the widget**

```
from kivy.uix.video import Video

video_list = ['your_video.mp4'] # Can uses a list of videos

class PlayerOpen(Video):
    video_list = ['vid.mp4']
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.v = 0
        super().__init__(source=video_list[0], state='stop', **kwargs)

    def on_eos(self, *args):
        print(f'on_eos: {self.eos} loaded: {self.loaded}, state: {self.state}')
        if self.eos:
            self.v += 1
            if self.v == len(video_list):
                print('End of playlist')
                self.v = 0
                return
        self.source = video_list[self.v]
        self.state = 'play'  # must set state to play for video to be loaded

    def on_loaded(self, *args):
        print(f'loaded: {self.loaded}')
```

I know this isn't exactly what you asked for, but this might be able to solve your problem as you could still get the animation playing in your loading screen.  Hope it helps

Comment: I have Gif Image now but why is the program showing me an error why why ?

Comment: @YassinMrd I don't know why your code crashed but I have had some issues with using .gif files, it just loaded a still frame.  My solution was the convert the gif to an mp4 and them implement the solution above.

Comment: @YassinMrd My only other suggestion would be adding 'anim_delay: -1' and 'anim_loop: 1' as parameters under the Image object (Below the post hint).  They are in the docs and all other examples of gifs I could find